# predictive model that includes previous predictions and models time dependence

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, python, negative-binomial-distribution, disease

I'm trying to predict counts of dengue fever from climate and environmental data. I'm predicting total weekly counts of dengue and the data is time-series in one week intervals over the past 20 years.  I need to predict the next 10 years (dengue weekly counts is absent from that dataset). I'm using python and find that negative binomial regression, support vector regressor, and random forest regressor work fairly well, but they cannot account for the large outbreaks and contagiousness of the disease.

Does anyone know how to build a model that progressively predicts a new value while taking into account the previous prediction?

Thank you!

Comment: You could include lagged variables in your regression possibly to account for activity in the previous week, month, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterative prediction to do so. You train a model for predicting one week in advance. Then you add your prediction computed with the model in your dataset and train an other model with the prediction as a feature.
For example, if you want to predict 4 weeks in advance, you will train 4 models, the last 3 containing the predictions computed before.

With this procedure, you will take into account the previous prediction but you will need to train n models if you want to predict n weeks in advance.

You can see my answer to a similar problem on stackoverflow (a little bit more elaborate) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581545/machine-learning-algorithm-to-predict-next-value/42583196#42583196